# Why is my if statement running incorrectly?

Tags: python, if-statement

My if statement here in line 4 and 6 keep running even if the user inputs the correct word. I'm confused. Any suggestions? Have been trying to get this to work for a day now.

```py
boi = input("Do you want to enter a part of a house or a word, (\"house part\" or \"word\")? ")
print(boi)
if boi != "house part":
    print("I do not understand", boi +".")
elif boi != "word":
    print("I do not understand", boi + ".")
if boi == "house part":
    hp = input("Please enter a part of a house: ")
    print(hp)
    if hp == "basement":
        print("calf")
    elif hp == "wall":
        print("skin")
    elif hp == "attic":
        print ("hip")
    elif hp == "kitchen":
        print("abdomen")
    elif hp == "study":
        print("wrist")
    else:
        print("I do not know anything about a(n)", hp + ".")
elif boi == "word":
    w = input("Please enter a word: ")
    print(w)
    if w == "attorney":
        print("macilmud")
    elif w == "chicken":
        print("sleent")
    elif w == "consider":
        print("floria")
    elif w == "application":
        print("sailinexemy")
    elif w == "prepare":
        print("capied")
    else:
        print("I do not know anything about a(n)", w + ".")
```

Comment: @Harith Why do you think that will make any difference?

Comment: `print("I do not understand", boi +".")` is guaranteed to print based on the logic you've given. You probably mean `if boi != "house part" and boi != "word":` instead of two separate branches. Welcome to SO, BTW.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!! Unfortunately, it didn't work, but I'll keep looking. Thank you! ^^

Comment: @ggorlen, your suggestion worked! Thank you so much! :DD Thanks for the welcome, too!

Comment: @harith If it's logically the same, the code will run the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you want validating input, you can use instead of this part in below:

```
if boi != "house part":
    print("I do not understand", boi +".")
elif boi != "word":
    print("I do not understand", boi + ".")
```

use this:

```
if boi != "house part" and boi != "word":
    print("I do not understand", boi +".")
```

Comment: This should be `and` not `or` otherwise the issue will remain

Answer (score 2):

All inputs will either be not one or not the other.  you need to combine these two into a single condition such as:

```
if boi not in ("house part","word"):
    print("I do not understand", boi + ".")
```

or, more simply, add a final else: to the next condition (and remove the first one).

```
if boi == "house part":
    ...
elif boi == "word":
    ...
else:
    print("I do not understand", boi + ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```py
if boi != "house part":
    print("I do not understand", boi +".")
elif boi != "word":
    print("I do not understand", boi + ".")
```

Entering `house part` will result in `I do not understand house part.` as `house part` is not equal to `word` which satisfies the `elif boi != "word":`. It looks like you'd want to combine the two statements into one:

```py
if boi not in ("house part", "word"):
```

This is because your current code runs like this:

```py
#user enters "house part"
if boi != "house part": 
#boi is equal to "house part" so the if returns 
#false and continues to the elif
    print("I do not understand", boi +".")
elif boi != "word":
#boi is not equal to "word" so the elif is satisfied and 
#the below statements are run.
    print("I do not understand", boi + ".")
```